# Increase timeout value in AWS ElasticBeanstalk with Application Load Balancer for Amazon Linux 2

Tags: nginx, timeout, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to increase the value of Timeout in AWS Elasticbeanstalk with Load Balancer, behind nginx.
What I did so far is to create a

> .ebextensions

folder, and inside a file with these 2 configurations:

```
 files:
   "/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.custom.conf":
       mode: "644"
       owner: "root"
       group: "root"
       content: |
         client_header_timeout   1300;
         client_body_timeout     1300;
         send_timeout            1300;
         proxy_connect_timeout   1300;
         proxy_read_timeout      1300;
         proxy_send_timeout      1300;

 container_commands:
   01_restart_nginx:
     command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

And then I tried with this:

```
 option_settings:
   - namespace: aws:elbv2:loadbalancer
     option_name: IdleTimeout
     value: 2000
```

None of them seem to be working, and haven't found anything else out there in google.
Anyone knows how to do this, without having to enter to the server and modify the config file manually?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe this helps? https://medium.com/p/189b844ab6ad

Answer (score 0):

So, the problems were 2:

- First, I'm using Amazon Linux 2, so instead of `.ebextensions` folder should create `.platform` folder.
- Second, to deploy my application I have a build step in which typescript code is compiled into vanilla javascript and moved to a `/dist` folder. During the build I had to copy also the folder `.platform` to the `dist` folder.

To do it, in the root folder, create a directory `.platform/nginx/conf.d/my-file.conf`. Inside it I just increased the values:

```
client_header_timeout   900;
client_body_timeout     900;
send_timeout            900;
proxy_connect_timeout   900;
proxy_read_timeout      900;
proxy_send_timeout      900;
```

And that's all, worked perfectly.